# How to fix Xcode analyze issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

How to fixed iOS analyze issues like "Potential leak of an object stored into"
[image]

CODE

```
ABMultiValueRef email = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
txtEmail.text = ( NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(email, 0));


ABMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
txtTelel.text = ( NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, 0));
```

Comment: It's much better to paste code into your question instead of using a screenshot. Same with the error message.

Comment: By using long and complicated lines of code you are hiding your bug. Things get more obvious if you introduce another temporary variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ABMultiValueRef email = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
txtEmail.text = ( NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(email, 0));
CFRelease(email);


ABMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
txtTelel.text = ( NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, 0));
CFRelease(multi);
```